# Frameworks to use to build applications handling text

Tags: objective-c

What are the tird-party frameworks that are more useful to create a generic application? I am looking for a framework that is well documented, and that would allow me to not write from zero a set of classes that every applications should have.
There are some frameworks made available free from some software houses, but the documentation is not enough to help to use the framework.

Comment: I believe the first step in getting your wish would be to identify the features you need for your 'generic app'. This list would allow you to zero in on a potential fwk by process of elimination.

Comment: the basic tone of your question, and that you're looking for "a set of classes that every application should have", makes me wonder what basic functionality isn't found in most built-in language frameworks?

Comment: There are features that we are used to see in many applications, but they are not directly implemented in Cocoa. I am looking for a framework that would simplify the development of a text editor with syntax highlighting; if then the framework would also have a class to create a menu extras with all the features seen in the system menu extras, that would be something good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've perused the system's integrated frameworks/capabilities, and not knowing what you need beyond them, I recommend:

http://www.omnigroup.com/developer/

EDIT:
In response to the clarification:

For string colorization and syntax highlighting, there are classes like CFAttributedString and NSAttributedString. That will require you to parse the sources, but is the basis for simple text drawing. You may also want to see CoreText.framework (ships with OS X). For something that would likely require the least work, Scintilla was (last I checked) in the process of supporting OS X. Though I do not know of a framework that meets all your marks in that regard.

Regarding AppleScript: Apple does provide these some applescript objects (syntax colorization by `- [NSApplescript richTextSource]`). Apple has not provided this support for other languages, and it is a very long, complicated process, depending on the languages you'd like to support. If there are many, I would choose Scintilla.

Comment: That is what I meant; I am looking for a framework to use beyond the system frameworks; Cocoa is a good framework to build applications, but using it still requires you to write code that could be made more generic, and used in more applications.Just to make an example, if I am writing a text editor with syntax highlighting, I would write code to highlight the text using different colors, and that code can be made generic enough to be used also in a Quicklook plugin.

Comment: To make another example, if I am writing an application that handles text, and which implements AppleScript integration, I would probably need some classes that would be probably be made generic enough to be used from any text editor with AppleScript support. If those classes have been already written, then I would not need to write those classes.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard that [Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/) is a great framework for Mac development. :)

**Edit: ** Now that I know what you're looking for, here's some links:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/smultron/ (An open source text editor. You might be able to use some of the code here)

http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/Cocoa%20Text%20System.html (A huge post about the Cocoa text system)

http://www.dabble.org/viallover/#downloads (Another open source project which makes text entry respond like vi)

Good Luck!

Comment: I was going to reply 'Foundation', but figured I'd have been pummeled.

Comment: Cocoa covers a lot of what anyone would need for a 'generic' application. I would dare to say if you need stuff not in Cocoa you're done with your 'generic' part of your app and are now building the specifics. For specifics you search for frameworks that provide specific functionality not included with Cocoa ... I would assume you are talking about JSON parser and stuff like that ...

Comment: What I am interested is a framework for a text editing application, with syntax highlighting; if then the framework would also simplify the development of features that are common to many applications, that would be fine too. Cocoa has classes that are the base upon which to build an application; still, there is code that needs to be written specifically for an application. Cocoa is very good, and probably I will simply build an application on it; I was wondering if there are frameworks that, like the ones created by Omnigroup, contains code common for a group of applications.

Comment: I understand that it has been my mistake to refer to generic applications, as in that case the only framework you could suggest would be a framework for the generic part of an application. I should had reported to which group the application belongs to (text editor, image editor, web service, etc).

Comment: OK, I understand more. I was just poking fun with my answer, but I think you'll probably end up learning Cocoa. I've put some links above to text editing resources.

Answer (score 0):

Identifying your project needs is the most important step.  If there were a end-all be-all framework then everyone would use it and you would probably already know the answer to this question.  There is no jesus of frameworks.  From the basic sense of your question, I'm wondering if you have dug deep enough into the built-in framework of your chosen language?  Most (good) languages have some built in libraries that accomplish most "basic" or "generic" tasks.

Once you dig deep enough into your language to find the bottom, THAT is when you need to look for a framework.

Comment: I am sorry; I didn't report the kind of applications I needed the framework for, but I understood now that the most generic answer would be to use Cocoa. I am looking for a framework that can be used from an application handling text, and that highlights the text. The code can be the baase for a text editor, a snippets collector, a Quicklook plugin. You are right saying that if there would be a framework generic enough to be used by everyone, then I would know already which one is it, and I would be already using it.